# Share Django authentication for FastAPI

Tags: python, django, authentication, fastapi

I have working Django project. Now i want to add FastAPI so at existing django templates i can make API requests to refresh data without reloading whole template (like tables for example).

The question is how to connect FastAPI to existing django authentication system, so it can use sessions from db, so that user authenticate only once, when logging in to django project.

Here some options i have investigated:

1. Change django base authentication to oauth2, also set fastapi to oauth2 (though i desire to configure fastapi, not changing django)
2. Fetch django sessions from db on each api request and verify user

Both django and fastapi on the same server and can share the same db.

Maybe some better options are possible. **Please advice what would be the best approach to use django already authenticated user data with fastapi?** Thx

Comment: What is the reason for using FastAPI in this context? Wouldn't using something like django rest framework be better for this use case, as it integrates with django and your existing infrastructure? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ - allowing you to use all your existing models, authentication, etc. If you decide to go with FastAPI, you'll usually have to read the session cookie into Javascript and then include it as an authorization token (since third party cookies can't be trusted to work automagically any longer).

Comment: @MatsLindh 
The reasons are few:
1) In the future i plan to migrate to React, so my whole backend would be fastapi, not django, because its faster
2) If i move to DRF then i will trigger whole django stack on each request, fastapi should be much faster

Comment: If you really want to go down that road, then the scheme with including the session cookie as an Authorization header and then looking that up in the django database on the FastAPI side should work. Depending on what you want to achieve you might have to perform authorization as well (i.e. whether the user has access to the given resource or not).

Comment: @MatsLindh 
So my steps are:
1) Get user session cookie from browser +username and add to api authorization header
2) Upon recieving api request get that session and check if it exist at db
3) Recheck that session cookie is not expired
Do i get it right? 
For step 3 i need to somehow decode that session cookie?

Comment: There isn't any reason to get the username; the session token (stored in a cookie) is the only thing that is used to authenticate the user. I'm not familiar with how Django structures its session token, but if it has an expiry field in the session database, make sure to add a WHERE-clause that compares the expiry time to the current time when looking it up.

Comment: @MatsLindh
ok, got it. Yes, django store expire_date. Are there any possible vulnerabilities if i send session cookie in api header? Like csrf attacks if its stolen or anything else?